# Constantly offsetting Position of an SKNode - Swift Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a Sprite SKNode Class which works like a StackView. In Sprite Kit objects origin is always centered therefore I would like to offset the position by a certain amount (which is `calculateAccumulatedFrame().width/2`) so it can be positioned comfortable. What would be the best way to do so?

First I thought I could do something like this

```
override var position: CGPoint {
    didSet {
        self.position = CGPoint(x: position.x - self.calculateAccumulatedFrame().width/2, y: position.y)
    }
}
```

But of course this is not possible since this would end in an endless loop
What would be other options?

Answer (score 0):

> In Sprite Kit objects origin is always centered

That is not true. There is this useful property called [`anchorPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/1519877-anchorpoint) that you can set to specify where the "origin" is.

Judging from your code, you seem to want the anchor point to be on the midpoint of the right edge of the sprite, assuming the sprite to be a rectangle. This means that you want the anchor point to be `(1, 0.5)`:

```
yourSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
```

Comment: Well but when I addChildren to an SKNode its frame does not get changed and therefore it does not get centered correctly

Comment: I dont use SKSpriteNode therefore I dont have the property anchorPoint, I use SKNode